# Post filename in label from Fileupload control - ASP.NET 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Is there anyway to run an event after i selected a file in a Fileupload control, so i can set Label1.Text = FileUpload.FileName;

Or if any of you got another idea that would be awesome too(maybe some javascript)! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for the `change` event on the client side. Here's the syntax for IE but you can adapt it for the better browsers.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> <span id="txt" />
    <script>
        var fu = document.getElementById('<% =FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
        fu.attachEvent('onchange', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = e.srcElement.value;
        });
    </script>
```

I'm pretty sure good browsers will report only the filename, where IE with report the full path too (incorrectly).

Comment: @Fogh are you calling `addEventListener` instead of `attachEvent` for browsers that require it? are you getting a proper reference to the element in browsers that don't support `srcElement`?